# TFS2010 Customer access via internet Website

Tags: tfs

Wondering if its possible (technically and licensing) to create a website for a Customer to view reports, report bugs, track progress of products we are creating for them (we are using VS2010 and TFS2010).

Cheers, Nick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully one of the MSFT guys will weigh in here, but if I recall, providing access to "real-time" data via a web site is not allowed.  Putting static data into a status report is allowed, I believe, as long as the person creating the data has a CAL.

There's an exception to the CAL requirement for creating work items and the subsequent view of those work items.  This would allow non CAL-ed users to be able to submit things like bug reports.

From a technical standpoint-- yeah, it is not only possible, but relatively easy to do with the API.

Comment: is exactly correct. In addition you should note that you can't setup and automated subscription to run and distribute reports to people without a CAL, but you could have a monkey with a CAL press a button once a day to distribute the reports :)